# Is there a function to efficiently subtract two matrices and return a tensor?

Tags: performance, pytorch

I want to efficiently reimplement the OpenCV BruteForce Matcher in pytorch. This means I get two matrices containing feature descriptors and I have to compute the distances between them. 
Currently I do it like this:

```
m, n, d = 10000, 1000, 2
x = torch.Tensor(size=(m, d))
y = torch.Tensor(size=(n, d))
dist = torch.sum(torch.stack([x-y_i for y_i in y]), (2,)) ##slow
dist = dist.numpy()
matches = np.argsort(dist)[:,:2]
good_matches = []
for i, (a, b) in enumerate(matches):
    if dist[i,b] > ratio*dist[i, a]:
        good_matches.append([i,a])
return good_matches
```

Is there any operation to speed this up? Is pytorch multiprocessing a good way to go?